# 2 синхронных select с сортировкой по алфавиту

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

На сайте есть 2 синхронных select,

```
<select name="index"  class="airports" id="index">                                                            
      <?php foreach ($indexes as $k) :?>
      <option><?=$k?></option>
      <?php endforeach;?>
</select>

<select name="airport"  class="airports" id="airname">        
       <?php foreach ($airports as $k) :?>
       <option><?=$k?></option>
       <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

соединённых скриптом

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
                airname.onchange=function(){Array.from(airname.options).map((v,i)=>{if(v.selected) index.value=Array.from(index.options)[i].value})}
                index.onchange=function(){Array.from(index.options).map((v,i)=>{if(v.selected) airname.value=Array.from(airname.options)[i].value})}
      });
</script>
```

Массивы $indexes и $airports берутся из БД, значения каждого элемента обоих массивов записано в своей строке , то есть

```
   index | airport
   -------------------
   UHWW  | Владивосток
   URMG  | Грозный
   UIII  | Иркутск
```

То есть порядок элементов правильный , и индексу соответствует правильный аэропорт. JS отрабатывает правильно.

Но мне нужно отсортировать индексы по алфавиту. 
Делаю я это с помощью функции natsort(), или же можно отсортировать прямо в запросе к БД.
Но тогда порядок элементов сбивается, и выбирается не правильный option во втором select.

Как нужно переписать javascript чтобы это исправить???

Comment: ну как самый простой вариант, добавить data-arrt для option, и сортировать по ним (во втором случае, при выводе в php добавить ключ, и по ключу выводить из массива $indexes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание, что индекс и название это свойства аэропорта. Аэропорт это объект в терминах ООП. И рассматривать его свойства и их взаимодействие нет никакого смысла. Из базы следует выбирать `$airports`, состоящий из элементов с полями `index` и `name` (неудачное именование полей в бд возможно вас и сбивает).

А дальше всё просто: дважды обходите `$airports` чтобы собрать два селекта. При обходе используйте свойство value у option:

```
<select name="index" class="airports" id="index">
    <?php foreach ($airports as $airport): ?>
        <option value="<?= htmlspecialchars($airport['index']) ?>">
            <?= htmlspecialchars($airport['index']) ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>

<select name="airport" class="airports" id="airname">
    <?php foreach ($airports as $airport): ?>
        <option value="<?= htmlspecialchars($airport['index']) ?>">
            <?= htmlspecialchars($airport['name']) ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Обратите внимание, что и в первом и во втором списке значение одно и тоже! Ведь индекс однозначно указывает на аэропорт и два списка нужны только для удобства пользователя.

Теперь при изменении одного из селектов, выставляйте такое же значение во втором.

UPD:

Если для удобства пользователя селекты надо отстортировать по алфавиту, то сделайте это с помощью функции `usort`. Например так:

```
usort($airports, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['index'] <=> $b['index'];
});
```

Comment: да так работает правильно, но первый селект не отсортирован по алфавиту

Comment: @Dmitriy добавил про usort.  Вы просто сортируете массив как вам нужно строите селект.